# Put a form key-values subset in a scope parameter

Tags: java, jsp

I've got a form (not linked with Spring pojos) with questions and answers.

I want to retrieve a String which contains only the key-values, like `Q1=A1_3&Q2=A2_1` and so on. I was doing that using Spring `@RequestBody` annotation.

The problem is that if I put an hidden field ("code") in the form, I'll get its value at the end of this string, and I don't want to mix the questions-answers key-values with the hidden field value.

This is my JSP:

```
<form name="pollform" method="post" action="1/submitpoll.do">
  <input type="hidden" name="code" value="C1"></input>

    <h4>T1Q1. How do you blabla?</h4>
        <input type="radio" name="Q1" value="A1_1">Very Good</input><br/>
        <input type="radio" name="Q1" value="A1_2">Could be better</input><br/>
        <input type="radio" name="Q1" value="A1_3">Bleah.</input><br/>

    <h4>T1Q2. Are you even bliblibli?</h4>
        <input type="radio" name="Q2" value="A2_1">Yes sure</input><br/>
        <input type="radio" name="Q2" value="A2_2">Not everytime</input><br/>
        <input type="radio" name="Q2" value="A2_3">Never</input><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

This way, using `@RequestBody` in my controller I'll get something like `Q1=A1_2&Q2=A2_3&code=C1` (and it's not what I want since I have to convert the result string in a HashMap later).

So, how can I get only the questions key-values of the form, excluding the hidden input value?
Should I use jstl or something else?

Answer (score 0):

If you need map of question-answer pairs and the hidden code parameter, I suggest to introduce model object, which will contain the code and the map, and let the spring make the mapping for you. Checkout this [example](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-mvc-hashmap-form-example/). There is map of contact details to be saved by controller, similar to your map of answers to questions.